# GA's Measurement Protocol is sending events to the wrong view and not because of filters

Tags: google-analytics, measurement-protocol

I'm trying to send an event to GA using their measurement protocol events, however, the damn thing is not going into `All website data`. Rather it goes into a different view I have created. I made sure to double-check filters and they should not be blocking the event as I have seen others having solved the issue caused by filters. Tried using both `POST` and `GET` as well to no avail. Any and all suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the exact hit you are sending.   collect endpoint is HTTP Post debug end point is HTTP Get.   Make sure that you dont have Exclude all hits from known bots and spiders enabled in the view that you are missing data from.

Comment: Turning off 'Exclude all hits from known bots' seemed to fix it. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you dont have `Exclude all hits from known bots and spiders` enabled in the view that you are missing data from.

This was an addition made a few years back to reduce the hits from referral spammers. Unfortunately if you are using the measurement protocol  directly you tend to be detected as a spammer

Comment: That was indeed the issue here. De-selecting it solved it. Thanks, @DamlTo , for the quick reply!

Comment: In our case it worked too, but it seemed to take a few hours to take effect.